# Snowflake: Data Split from AWS US to AWS Australia

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssis, replication, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There is 10TB of data in SNOWFLAKE db in AWS US region.  The requirement is to split a subset of data with certain flag in a column to AWS Australia region.
After split, the US data will be around 6TB and Australia around 4TB.
There are 10 applications containing this mix of data.
I could think of 3 options to do this split.

*1. Replicate the entire database from A to B.  Then pause application before breaking the replication. In B, delete data in B database where filter is A's data.  In A, repeat the delete where filter is B's data.  Clone application set and configure new set to read/write to B*

*2. Use CTAS in B with data from A*

*3. Use SSIS to push data from A to B.  For this option, the application need not be stopped.*

Please advise on these options and if there is/are anymore options in which this data split can be achieved.

Regards,
Mani

Comment: I guess it depends on the activity on the source and whether there is a window to allow such things but perhaps look at clone and swap commands? So make a US clone from A on source and make appropriate changes to it then at go-live swap it with A. Also make a AUS clone from A when creating US clone & remove data then replicate this to target. At go-live the action on that side is to promote it to be the primary. There are a lot of assumptions here but might be a possible route?...more on the SWAP command here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-database.html#parameters

Comment: Thanks Mike Donovan.  I will check the document.

Answer (score 0):

The whole setup on how these 10 applications access your snowflake table are unclear, but important to provide a solution.

Your best option to sync data over two snowflake accounts is using database replication failover:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/database-replication-failover.html

To split data based on a field can easily be done with materialized views that have a where clause containing this field. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-materialized.html